# Homework question about an engine pulling a train

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

> An 8000 kg engine pulls a train of 5 wagons, each of 2000 kg, along a
>   horizontal track. If the engine exerts a force of 40000N , calculate the acceleration of the train.

To find the acceleration of the train , I divided 40000N by mass of 5 wagons. 
But in the book the mass of the engine was also included for finding the acceleration.

I cannot understand how is the force of 40000 N acting on (engine + wagons). According to me this should only act on the wagons as the engine is applying this force.

Comment: This is a poorly worded question. I read (like you) that the engine exerts 40000 N on the train of wagons.  What they should have said is that the net force on the engine and train is 40000 N, if the mass of the engine was involved. The only correct answer is to give both situations.  The book is wrong.

Comment: It's tricky but it says "the engine exerts a force" it does not say " the engine exerts a force on the cars".  And that's the reason you include the engine!

Comment: It does say that the engine pulls the train... You have to read the whole question and not just the last sentence.

Comment: The problem is ambiguously worded, but I'm shocked that you have all forgotten to include the vertical force exerted by the weight of the engine on the ground! Surely, we're meant to subtract that out from the 40kN total force. Since the question does not specify what the local gravity is on the train's planet, we clearly cannot solve it.

Comment: @Xerxes This is completely wrong. The vertical forces cancel each other and have nothing to do with the horizontal force pulling the train. You forget the normal force exerted by the ground on the train.

Comment: @nasu The cancelling normal force is exerted on, not by, the engine.

Comment: Can someone tell me what is an OP?

Comment: @Xerxes Same is true for the gravity acting on the engine. So the two forces (on the engine) cancel and they contribute nothing to the net force.  Bringing in gravity here is irrelevant. And subtracting the weight from the engine's thrust force does not make sense. Unless you have the train going up a ramp. Draw a force diagram and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: @Broly "Original poster" or "Original post" depending on context (that is the person who posted first, or the first post which was made)

Comment: @user49915 yeah,that's a funny coincidence

Comment: @nasu You are assuming facts not in evidence. "Thrust force" is never mentioned in the problem. The only force mentioned is exerted by the engine on some unspecified object. If we assume that object is the rails, well, then we must subtract the gravity component to determine the force in the forward direction. But then we have to assume a direction... There is a lot of assuming needed to solve this problem.

Comment: @Broly: as a side note, another similar common abbreviation (though not in Stack Exchange sites) is GP. It means Grand Parent = two comments up in a thread "(the parent comment of the comment to my comment".

Comment: Usually questions give you exactly what you need to solve the problem - i.e. they wouldn't give you the mass of the train unless they wanted you to use it.

Comment: @LamarLatrell Not true.  Questions often give more than enough information. However, if they do omit some information (like the mass of a car, etc.) then it isn't needed.  It's a poorly worded question. The engine exerts forces on several other objects: the rails, the train cars, and the earth to name three obvious ones.

Answer (score 11):

The question is ambiguous, but I think we are meant to assume that the engine exerts a force of $40000$ N on the track. From the reaction force of $40000$ N on the engine some part, say $F_1$, is acting to accelerate the engine itself and some other part, say $F_2$, is exerted on the wagons. The acceleration of the engine and of the wagons is the same, so if this acceleration is $a$ then

$F_1 = 8000a \\ F_2 = 10000a \\ 40000 = F_1 + F_2 = 18000a \\ \Rightarrow a = \frac{40000}{18000}$

Comment: I agree, the wording includes the engine.

Comment: I would argue that the engine exerts the force on the track, and the reaction force is what accelerates the (whole) train (engine+wagons). Otherwise the problem would have specified the force acting at the first coupling, or used some indication like "net".

Comment: @CCTO Agreed - I will add this to my answer.

Comment: The OP's question is a good one, but I don't think that the test question is ambiguous in the slightest. It seems to me that the OP's misunderstanding of it is exactly the sort of misunderstanding that this question is designed to test.

Comment: @bornfromanegg I think the ambiguity comes from the word "engine". if we assume that the engine is a moving engine i.e. a locomotive then the $40000$ N is accelerating both the engine and the wagons. But "engine" could possibly mean stationary engine, in which case the $40000$ N is accelerating only the wagons and the mass of the engine is irrelevant.

Comment: @gandalf61 I agree with what you say, but I’m not convinced that that was the OP’s misunderstanding. Ask a hundred people to imagine an engine pulling a train, and I doubt many of them would imagine a stationary engine. On a side note, it’s worth pointing out that that interpretation would mean the mass of the engine was irrelevant. Ignoring information given in a test question is a good indication that you’re doing something wrong.

Comment: I only took one year of physics in high school, and it seems pretty self evident to me that, in order to accelerate the train, the engine has to accelerate itself too (and thus its mass is relevant). If the engine isn't being accelerated (presumably from a stop?), then how is it exerting its force on the rest of the cars, considering the only means it has to exert force is by pushing or pulling via the linkage to the rest of the cars? The question didn't say the engine was stationary and had some sort of weird, specialized push-bar or tow winch to move the cars without moving itself.

Comment: Strange things happen when common sense is left out of the equation ;)

Comment: @DoktorJ The engine exerts a force of 40 kN, but on what? If we interpret this to be on the first wagon in the train, then the mass of the engine is irrelevant. This is how I would have interpreted this ambiguous problem. You even acknowledge this possibility when you say "how is it exerting its force on the rest of the cars, considering the only means it has to exert force is by pushing or pulling via the linkage". That is the force I (and presumably OP) assumed the question provided.

Comment: @Matt Clearly, interpretation is key, and application of science to real world situations requires interpretation. I’m interested to know how you might reword the question so that it was not ambiguous, but still required analysis (rather than just ‘put these numbers in the equation’).

Comment: @bornfromanegg The question should include a partial force diagram indicating the applied force. Alternatively something like "the engine applies a forward force of 40 kN on the tracks" would probably work. The question wanted the students to calculate f/m=a, after finding the appropriate m. They can easily do this without ambiguity.

Answer (score 8):

IMO you're right: the problem's wording is bad. It's meaningless to say "the engine exerts a force of 40000 N". The engine interacts both with the first wagon and with the rail, exerting forces on both and these forces are different. How can we know what the book's author had in mind? If the former, your answer is right, if the latter, the book's one is right. Of course in the latter case (force exerted on rail) it's not that force which accelerates the train, but the rail's reaction.

As a general rule we shouldn't say "A exerts a force" - much better "A exerts a force on B". Better yet "A exerts a force on point P of B". The point where a force acts can make a great difference.

**Edit**

Many things have been said but IMO it's useful to be still clearer. After further reflections I think it's not wording that's bad, but the thinking behind.

As already stated e.g. by @Farcher in mechanics problems the first thing to be done is to make clear which the (mechanical) system is. In our case, it's wagons or wagons + engine? Note that it wouldn't make
difference as to acceleration, which is the same for all parts of the train, but isn't by no means the same if forces are concerned. Consider the two choices:

a) The system consists of wagons alone. Then it makes sense to say that engine (which doesn't belong to the system) applies a given force $F$ to the system and compute acceleration as $a=F/m$, where 
$m=10000\,\rm kg$. Given the book's answer, this isn't the author's choice.

b) The system consists of the whole train, engine included. Then there are two alternatives as to the given force $F$ (here I'm reiterating)

b1) $F$ is a force engine applies to wagons. Then it's an *internal* force and as such it *cannot* accelerate the system. Its acceleration is only due to the net *external* force (in computing the resultant internal forces cancel thanks to third Newton's law). Then the
solution is nonsense.

b2) $F$ is a force engine applies to external world. In that case it will never accelerate the system or a part of it. It could accelerate the rail, were it not firmly fixed to ground. Not to mention that a force engine applies to rail exists, but is in the wrong direction.

So not even choice b) is acceptable. Neither as it's used in gandalf61's answer.

I'd like to add another comment. Unfortunately "engine" in English may mean two different things: either the motor proper (electric, diesel,
or else) which ultimately is the cause of motion - or the car carrying it. Of course the datum of mass suggests the latter interpretation. But my suspicion is that the author - maybe without realizing - thought
of the former.

I'm led to say so because it's a very common way of thinking about cars and other motorized vehicles. If you ask someone "which force causes a car move?" I bet you'll get as an answer "the motor's force". Nobody thinks that in strict mechanical meaning the motor can only produce *internal* forces and as such will never move a car by a cm. That the only *external* force which can put a car in motion is the road's friction on the wheels.

Comment: Choice b is, acceptable. You just have to go one more step and apply the law of action and reaction. The force exerted on the rails accelerates the Earth, but the reaction accelerates the train.

Answer (score 4):

You have to add mass of engine also.The force is applied on whole system.What will be the acceleration of only engine if you remove wagons?You will consider it's mass also.

Comment: "The force is applied on whole system." That's NOT what the words of the problem say. The engine exerts a force---that must be on something else. In this type of analysis, things don't have self-forces.  It's a terrible question.

Comment: @Bill N: The engine exerts a force on the TRACK, which causes it to accelerate.  Since the engine is connected to the cars, it must accelerate them as well, so the mass being accelerated is engine + cars.

Comment: @jamesqf The engine also exerts a force on the tracks due to gravity. Since we were just given total force exerted by the engine on the tracks, don't forget to subtract the gravity portion when calculating the force accelerating the train.

Comment: @Matt As long as we're being pedantic, they don't say which planet this train is on, or if it's outer space, so the gravitational force is undefined and the question is unsolvable.

Comment: @NuclearWang Good point! But I disagree that accounting for gravity is pedantic. (Anyway, assuming earth is a pretty standard assumption for entry level physics) The question doesnt specify what the 40kN is exerted on. It could reasonably be on the first wagon in the line, or it could be the tracks. But in fact neither of these are what the "correct" answer assumes. I dont think its fair to expect arbitrary assumptions while also expecting the OP to ignore a very real, very important, force. Especially since the engine apparently exerts a net 40 kN on presisely zero objects.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine if you only had the engine by itself exerting the same 40,000N of thrust, to find the acceleration of the engine you would not do 40000/0kg would you? The 40,000N the engine exert is also used to thrust itself forward.

But let’s say it didn’t, and that only the wagons were pulled. Well now you have a stationary engine, pulling 5 wagons, each with an acceleration of 4m/s^2. These wagons will catch up to the engine in no  time and obliterate the engine from behind. we can at least agree this is not how train works

Comment: If the engine is by itself,, what is exerting thrust on? It can't exert thrust on itself. There must be something else exerting thrust on the engine.  Regarding your second paragraph, there is obviously some force acting on the engine, but we aren't told what it is. All we know is that the engine exerts a force of 40000 N, presumably on the train of wagons.

Comment: It's tricky but it says "the engine exerts a force" it does not say " the engine exerts a force on the cars". And that's the reason you include the engine!  The problem is solvable for either situation.

Comment: I do agree with Physics Dave. Though the very existence of this Q and some comments tell that the exercise could have been written more clearly.

Comment: @BillN on the rails, naturally.

Answer (score 2):

The question is flawed in that can be deemed to be ambiguous and therefore requires interpretation.

Using Newton’s second law requires the system under consideration to be defined and that has not been done in this question.

Without the system being defined the statement

> the engine exerts a force of 40000N

is the cause of the ambiguity.

So which is it?

**1** The engine is exerting an external force of 40000N on the system of five wagons.

**2** The engine exerts an internal force of 40000N on the system of five wagons and the engine.

**3** There is an external force of 40000N on the engine and five wagons.

The author of the book really meant option **3** but given the way the question was written I have to agree with the OP that an external force of 40000N is acting on the five wagons whcich is option **1**.

Answer (score 2):

## The force of 40 kN is exerted on the rails, not the wagons

We have to assume that the engine and wagons are all coupled together, and therefore that they move together. If the engine exerted a force on the wagons but did not move with them, the wagons would provide a different force in reaction. If the train was off the track, it would not be exerting that force on the wagons.

The engine turns the wheels which exert a force backwards on the rails, which also imparts the reaction forwards on the train.

That force is transmitted from the rails through the engine and the coupling to the wagons.

To take a different circumstance, suppose the train was going uphill? The engine will still exert a force of the same magnitude, but this time the balance of forces and angles are different, so the acceleration is different too.

Thus that force must accelerate the total mass of the engine and the wagons together.

Comment: No, the question is flawed/ambiguous. When you specify "A exerts a force ...." you must say what that force is exerted on.